# Is there a way to create a mouse-down drag event using Zelle's graphics module?

Tags: python, mouseevent, draggable, zelle-graphics

Using Zelle Graphics.py - is there a way to create a mouse-down draggable event?  I have an easy way to create points, but cannot get them to continue to draw as the mouse is dragged or while the button is pressed.  I am pretty sure that tkinter has a way of doing this, but I am unsure of how to incorporate that into this code.  Does graphics.py have a method?

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("drag", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)
point1 = Point(250, 250)
point1.draw(win)
while True:
    coord = win.checkMouse()
    if coord == None:
        pass
    else:
        point1 = Point(coord.getX(), coord.getY())
        point1.setFill("red")
        point1.draw(win)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `graphics` module's API doesn't expose `tkinter` event processing, so how do you proposed handling them — generally or at least this one "dragging" event — in the context of using it?  The `checkMouse()` function in the current implementation only returns the last place the mouse was clicked, if any. Generally speaking I'm pretty sure it would be possible to implement, however doing so would likely require changing the module itself since there's nothing currently in it to support this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with tkinter bindings and came up with this solution.  Now I am looking for a way to include a game loop in the mix.

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("drag", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)
point1 = Point(250, 250)
point1.draw(win)

def motion(event):
  x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
  point1 = Point(x1, y1)
  point1.setFill("red")
  point1.draw(win)

win.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion)
win.mainloop()
```